# Does windows 2016 server support hot add cpu?

Tags: windows, kvm, windows-server-2016, libvirt, hotplugging

Today, I created a KVM vm with windows 2016 server operation system by libvirt, and its memory can be hotplug with "virsh attachdevice" command, but vcpu cannot be hot-add with "virsh setvcpus". However, it is worked in windows 2008R2 and windows 2012R2 virtual machine, dose windows 2016 server support hot add cpu?

Answer (score 0):

The command "virsh setvcpus" was worked, and there is no error in libvirt/qemu log, but it not works in vm, only reboot the vm that cpu will be added.